# Why my nested form fail?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created nested form along with [this](http://davidlesches.com/blog/rails-nested-forms-using-jquery-and-simpleform) tutorial. Everything worked fine, for new object, but if I want to view edit form, I get this error

> undefined local variable or method `roles_form' for #<#:0x007f7c48ff6ab0>

Form:

```
  = simple_form_for @match do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    = f.input :club_home
    = f.input :club_away
    = f.input :address
    = f.input :date
    = f.simple_fields_for :roles do |r|
      %h3.text-center Referees
      .duplicatable_nested_form
        = r.input :role_type, collection: ["Referee", "Time/Scorekeeper", "Assessor", "Head Referee"], include_blank: false
        = r.association :showcase, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false

        - if @match.new_record?
          = link_to 'Remove', '', :remote => true, :class => 'destroy_duplicate_nested_form'
        - else
          = link_to 'Remove', match_roles_path(@match, roles_form.object), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'destroy_duplicate_nested_form'
          = roles_form.input :id, as: :hidden

    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    = link_to 'Add Another Referee', '', :class => 'duplicate_nested_form'
```

Match controller:

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @matches = Match.all
    @matches_grid = initialize_grid(Match)
  end

  def show
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    @referees = @match.referees
    @scorekeeper = @match.scorekeepers
    @assessor = @match.assessors
  end

  def new
    @match = Match.new
    @match.roles.build
  end

  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
    if @match.save
      flash[:success] = "Match created"
      redirect_to matches_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    @match.roles.build
  end

  def update
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    if @match.update_attributes(match_params)
      flash[:success] = "Match updated"
      redirect_to @match
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    @match.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Match destroyed"
    redirect_to matches_path
  end

  private

  def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:club_home, :club_away, :date, :address, roles_attributes: [ :id, :showcase_id, :role_type ])
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :matches do
    resources :roles, only: :destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: roles_form doesn't exists in the view you provide. you can use only f and r. from `simple_form_for @match do |f|` and `f.simple_fields_for :roles do |r|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see an error such as `undefined local variable or method`XYZ' for ...`, it means that you are attempting to use a variable named`XYZ` that does not exist in that scope.

In your case, you are trying to use `roles_form`

```
= roles_form.input :id, as: :hidden
```

but it does not exist. Instead, you named that variable `r` in the following line

```
= f.simple_fields_for :roles do |r|
```

You'll want to just replace instances of `roles_form` with `r` OR change `r` to `roles_form`.

Comment: Now I see edit view, but when I want to delete role, I get this error:  Started DELETE "/matches/1/roles/%23%3CSimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007f366ab522a8%3E" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-10 16:49:33 +0200
Processing by RolesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"match_id"=>"1", "id"=>"#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007f366ab522a8>"}

Comment: Glad you were able to get past the first issue. This second one has to do with your `link_to` path. Try `match_roles_path(@match, roles_form.object.id)` to indicate that you want the `id`, not the entire object itself

Comment: This part can look only like this to work: match_role_path(@match, r). If I change it to this: match_role_path(@match, r.object.id), I've got this error: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"roles", :id=>nil, :match_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Unfortunately, not. With this: match_role_path(@match, r) I can see edit view, but I cant remove role. With: match_role_path(@match, r.object.id), I can't even see view, and I'm receiving error: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"roles", :id=>nil, :match_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Ah I may have seen this before. In the controller you are building a new role (`@match.roles.build`) which means that this record won't have an `id` yet. This would cause an issue when trying to build that route. You have a line in there checking if the `@match` is a new record, however you really want to check if the *role* is a new record. E.g. `r.object.new_record?`

Comment: Great! Glad I could help